# How to run linux without any DesktopEnvironment?

Tags: linux, terminal, chroot, xfce

I have Manjaro installed on my system and for the Desktop Environment I have XFCE4 and for login manager LXDM everything works fine
but when I try to change some of the lxdm-config option I can't login to my user, the problem came from that I disable that option to shown the select session panel and after logout when I try to login again but after type password and press enter back to select user again!

I have no access to terminal or my user account to change the config again and back it to default or change the login session to xfce4

How can I access to terminal to change config or access to desktop or how can I fix this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try pressing CTRL+ALT+F2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using ALt+Ctrl +FnKey. Fn key from 1 to 6 would lead you to the terminal shell. you can use all the bash commands over there. 
You may restore the configuration file from there.

To reset display settings back to defaults (XFCE), this  [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2287826) may help you.